# How to make a numbe auto growing value when press in and stop when press out

Tags: react-native

I have tried using `setInterval` but it didn't work.

```
handlePressIn = () => {
    const {value} = this.state
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.setState({ value: value + 1}), 500) 
  }

  handlePressOut = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timerId)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
          onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
        >
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Animated.View style={styles.bgFill} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Press And Hold Me</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it :v

```
 handlePressIn = () => {
        const {value} = this.state
        this.setState({ increasing: true })
      }
    
      handlePressOut = () => {
        this.setState({ increasing: false })
      }
    
      check = () => {
        const { increasing, value } = this.state
        let i = value + 30
        if ( this.state.increasing ) setTimeout(() => this.setState({ value: i }),100)
      }
      
      increasing = () => {
        let i = this.state.value + 1
        this.setState({ value: i })
    
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.check()
        }, 500)
      }
```